# Notify polymer complex object has changed

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

How can I trigger a refresh of the template if a member of a data-bound complex object changes?

In the template:

```
<other-component data="{{complexObject}}"></other-object>
```

In the component:

```
_onChange: function(newData) {
   //callback from some event-system
   this.set("complexObject", newData);
}
```

The `_onChange`-Method is triggered when the complexObject is changed, but `newData` is always a reference to the same object, just members of this object changed - because of this, polymer doesn't update the view and doesn't pass the data down to `other-component`.

Is there a way to let polymer know that there is indeed some new data and it has to re-evaluate the template? It is working if I create a shallow clone of `newData`, but that seems like a hack and could hurt performance for big objects.

I can't use the `set` method to change the properties of the object via the path because the change happens outside of polymer-elements and I can't control it.

Comment: did you try calling `this.notifyPath("complexObject");` ?

Comment: @PascalGula I tried, but it didn't change anything. I digged through the polymer-sourcecode and this.set internally already calls notifyPath

Comment: do you have `notify: true` also set? :)

Answer (score 0):

Call render()

```
this.$.yourTemplateID.render();
```

Comment: what is yourTemplateID? I tried to give the <template>-tag in the dom-module an id, but this.$ is empty: <template id="maintemplate"> this.$.maintemplate === undefined

Answer (score 0):

Here is one working example where sibling elements are interchanging data between each other:  [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/40wf8L?p=preview).

Docs: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding

```
<template>
  <button on-tap="btnTapped">change Emploees from Second</button>
              second: empl: <span>{{empl.employees.0.firstName}}</span>
</template>
...
<script>
btnTapped: function () {

    console.log('Second: btnTapped');

    //Propagate array subproperty
    this.set('empl.employees.0.firstName', 'Test');
    console.log(this.empl.employees[0].firstName);


    //Object set
    this.set('temp.firstName', 'Test');

  }
</script>
```

Comment: while this is a good way, the code updating the complexObject is independent of polymer and web-components (3rd party lib)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.complexObject = _.clone(this.complexObject)
```

cloning & reassigning might solve this problem`

Comment: I already thought of that (see 2nd paragraph, 2nd sentence), but I was wondering whether there is a better way to handle this